# For Excel, Is it possible for a cell to automatically act as if someone clicked the "Enter" button on a keyboard for it?

Tags: excel, vba

A difficult question to word.

I have a VBA that is tied to the value of a specific cell. This VBA automatically sends an email out if the number in the cell is between 420 - 430. The formula for that particular cell is a running sum of an entire column. The cell is G1.

When the cell value is between 420 - 430, the email is only sent out if I click on the formula of that cell and hit enter on my keyboard. The email will not populate automatically, I still consider it manual since someone still needs to double click on the cell and hit enter.

Is there a way around this? Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
Dim xRg As Range
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("G1"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value >= 420 And Target.Value <= 430 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "The Employee named in the Subject of this email has exceeded 420 FMLA Hours. Please act accordingly. Thank you"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "osichicagohr@osigroup.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = [B2].Value
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
Sub Click_Cell()
ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Select
Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheet_Calculate()` event. The `Worksheet_Change` event doesn't fire when formulas recalculate. Note that since the `Calculate` event  has no `Target` parameter, you probably want to keep track of the value in that cell, possibly using a `Public` variable and the `Workbook_Open` event, and only sending the email when the value has exceeded the threshold.

Comment: Since it's a sum of the column, `worksheet_change()` should still work if ANY of the values change, then you can base the criteria for an email to be sent on the value of `G1`.  Your intersect would then involve `Intersect(Columns("G"),Target)`, assuming Column G is the one with the data being summed.

Comment: @Cyril A different column is the column being summed, but column G contains a Sum formula of that column (which happens to be column C). The email only triggers when the enter button is pressed on the keyboard of a cell, and I can't figure out a way to automate hitting "Enter" on a cell

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for responding. I'm not too familiar with VBA, would you be able to write an example of this? Would this go under its own separate sub?

Comment: @VinceG are you manually populating Column C?